# Can a @Html.ListBoxFor return the selected items instead of keys?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, model-binding

I have the following simple objects:

```
public class Thing
{
    public int ThingID { get; set; }
    public string ThingName { get; set; }
}

public class WrapperThing
{
    public List<Thing> SelectedThings{ get; set; }
    public List<Thing> UnselectedThings{ get; set; }
}

public class ThingStorageController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CreateThings(WrapperThing wt)
        if(ModelState.IsValid){
            //Modelstate has binding errors
        }
    }
}
```

What I want to have is something like this http://jsfiddle.net/timotheus/7JHA4/

What I currently have is this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("CreateThings", "ThingStorage"){
    @Html.ListBoxFor(x => x.SelectedThings, new MultiSelectList(Model.SelectedThings,"ThingId", "ThingName")
    <input id="thingSelect" type="button" value="<" />
    <input id="thingDeselect" type="button" value=">" />
    @Html.ListBoxFor(x => x.UnselectedThings, new MultiSelectList(Model.UnselectedThings,"ThingId", "ThingName")
}
```

This will give me Model errors on post saying it cant map strings onto object type of Thing which I suppose is correct as it's only sending back the ID's of the selected objects. Is there any way to post back the list of objects themselves?

Oh and as a bonus question, as you may want to consider this in your answer. I actually want to post back the entire contents of each list, not just the selected ones. Perhaps ListBoxFor() isn't the control I really want, can you suggest a better alternative for what I'm trying to achieve?

Comment: please add your action code and complete your view code

Comment: I think it's already quite clear but I've added the action and view form code anyway.

Comment: Why would you even want to that. just post back the the selected ID's and get the original collection in the controller and make the comparisons (rendering a whole lot of hidden inputs representing the collection and then posting the all back unchanged is only going to degrade performance). You seem to be wanting to mimic ViewState in WebForms.

Comment: If you want post a list in your action this article maybe useful for you, http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/

Comment: @StephenMuecke I could happily get the entire repo again in the controller and match against them but I was just surprised that I can't get the objects themselves back. Say I had a scenario where I got a WrapperThing out the DB and pushed it to the view. The user then swaps some items from one list to another and posts back. If I then want to change the properties of those objects in, say, the selectedThings list it means I have to go fetch all the Things that exist in the DB and match against them first. But perhaps thats still quicker than posting the lot. I was just curious if its possible.

Comment: Generally it would be quicker to call the DB again (and of course you could store the collection in session to speed it up further) - sending data to the client and back again is usually the bottleneck - but only you can test that. The only way to get full collection back from the view would be to render inputs for each property of each item in the collection.

Answer (score 1):

You could implement a custom model binder to map `SelectedThings` and `UnselectedThings` to instance of wrapper. However, you also want to post all things, which is not part of your wrapper model. Therefore, I would try and keep this simple.

The `ActionResult` receiving the post must accept parameters `int[] SelectedThings, int[] UnselectedThings`

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Submit(int[] SelectedThings, int[] UnselectedThings) 
{
     ... your code ...
}
```

To submit all things, you could implement a third `select` with id `AllThings` (perhaps  with `style="display:none"`) that would be backfilled with all options from `SelectedThings` and `UnselectedThings`. The backfilling could run during the `submit` event of the form.

```
$('form').submit(function() {
  $('#SelectedThings option').appendTo('#AllThings');
  $('#UnselectedThings option').appendTo('#AllThings');
}
```

If you do want to implement a custom model binder, take a look at [this post](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/605595/ASP-NET-MVC-Custom-Model-Binder)

And if you follow the post, I suggest inheriting from `DefaultModelBinder`. Here is a rough example that may get you started.

```
public class ThingModelBinder: DefaultModelBinder
{
    private List<Thing> ThingsData = new List<Thing> { new Thing { ThingId = 1, ThingName = "One" }, new Thing { ThingId = 2, ThingName = "Two" } };
    public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        //This assumes some persistance layer ThingsData
        //NOTE: you'll definately need to refactor this, but it should be enough to get you started
        if (bindingContext.ModelType == typeof(WrapperThing))
        {
            HttpRequestBase request = controllerContext.HttpContext.Request;

            //convert string to string[]
            string[] selected = request.Form.Get("SelectedThings").Split(Convert.ToChar(",")).ToArray<string>();
            // do the same with unselected


            //convert sting[] to int[]
            var iselected = (from i in selected select Convert.ToInt32(i)).ToArray<int>();
            // do the same with unselected

            //fill selected things
            List<Thing> fillSelected = (from data in ThingsData where iselected.Contains(data.ThingId) select data).ToList<Thing>();
            // do the same with unselected


            //instantiate WrapperThing and populate
            WrapperThing wrapper = new WrapperThing { SelectedThings = new List<Thing>(), UnselectedThings = new List<Thing>() };
            wrapper.SelectedThings = fillSelected;
            // you guessed it, do the same with unselected

            return wrapper;
        }

        return base.BindModel(controllerContext, bindingContext);
    }
}
```

As stated in the post, make sure you register the model binder in the appropriate place.

Comment: apologies for not being clear to start but I've updated my code with the action method to show that I'm looking for the wrapper object in return(as the wrapper will undoubtedly have other properties). So the problem exists because I don't want an array of ints(Id's) for the objects in the select list, I want the objects themselves. Any idea's how I can achieve this?

Comment: Answer updated with alternate approach. The approach follows the example demonstrated in the post.

Comment: I appreciate the effort but its still only posting back ID's at which point I need to match against a repository, in this case "ThingsData". I was hoping there might be a control or some way to get a listbox to display a property from an object but keep the object itself as the value to post back instead of just a designated key field of that object.

Comment: Agreed. Another option might be to use jquery/ajax for implementing the binding on the client side. You could use an ajax call to `Get` and `Post` a json version of the wrapper. A bit more client coding, but cleaner on the server side.